# How to declare a not null parameter into Store procedure in a right way?

Tags: sql-server

I wanna write a store procedure, which takes 4 parameters and one parameters must be entered, in order to find the right product to update it from the lager under different conditions. I do not know, where is my mistake. When i execute, i get such error **The parameter '@productName' has been declared as NOT NULL. NOT NULL parameters are only supported with natively compiled modules, except for inline table-valued functions.** I really appreciate your gently and kindly feedback to improve myself. I could not find the right answer online.

Here is my Code:

```
create procedure dbo.Update_Lager (@productName varchar (50) not null, @info varchar(30) null, @amount int null, @Preis float null)
as begin
    if (@productName != null)
        begin 
            if  (@info !=null and @amount !=null and @Preis != null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Info = @info, Anzahl = @amount, Preis = @Preis where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@info != null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Info = @info where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@amount!=null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Anzahl = @amount where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@Preis != null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Preis = @Preis where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    end
    else
        begin
            print ('You must enter the product name!')
        end
end
```

And this is the table.

[image: this is my table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like the below. Null and Not Null does not support in Parameter of Store Procedure

```
Create procedure dbo.Update_Lager (@productName varchar (50)='', 
@info varchar(30)=null, @amount int=null, @Preis float=null)
as begin
    if (@productName is not null)
        begin 
            if  (@info is not null and @amount is not null and @Preis is not null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Info = @info, Anzahl = @amount, Preis = @Preis where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@info is not null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Info = @info where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@amount is not null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Anzahl = @amount where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    else if (@Preis is not null)
        begin
            update Artikel set Preis = @Preis where Produktbezeichnung = @productName
        end
    end
    else
        begin
            print ('You must enter the product name!')
        end
end
```

Comment: As I explain in my own answer, this isn't going to work. This will **always** `PRINT` the message `'You must enter the product name!'`

Comment: hey thanks for your reply! when i write such a statement **exec dbo.Update_Lager 'Beans', 1.46;**, it doesn't update anything! could you guide me with last step as well, please?

Comment: Use **Is not null** instead of **!=Null**

Comment: thanks, now it worked but it updates the wrong fields, When i write **exec dbo.Update_Lager 'Beans', 1.46;**, it updates info field into Info columns and when i write **exec dbo.Update_Lager 'Beans','2kg bags' , 1.46;**, it still updates same field into same column but not other fields in other columns.

Comment: according to your above mention parameter, it will execute this query **update Artikel set Info = @info where Produktbezeichnung = @productName**

Answer (score 2):

Like the error tells you, SQL Server doesn't support `NOT NULL` parameters unless you're using natively compiled modules.

Also, in your query, `@productName != null` is *never* going to be True. ***Nothing*** is equal to, or not equal to `NULL`, **including** `NULL` itself. Both `NULL = NULL` and `NULL != NULL` returns "unknown", which although isn't false, it's more importantly **not** True (which is what we're testing for in boolean expressions). The only way to compare `NULL` values is with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Back to the question, however, if you need to implement a `NON NULL` parameter in a Procedure that isn't natively compiled, then you need to handle it within the Procedure. If you want to cause an error, then use `THROW` and a custom error message and number:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.TestProc @NullParam int = NULL, @NonNullParam int AS
BEGIN

    IF @NonNullParam IS NULL
        THROW 75001, N'Procedure ''TestProc'' expects a non-NULL value for parameter ''@NonNullParam'', which was not supplied.',16; --Choose a error number appropriate for you

    SELECT @NullParam + @NonNullParam;
END;
GO
--Works
EXEC dbo.TestProc @NullParam = 1,
                  @NonNullParam = 1;
GO

--Works (returns NULL)
EXEC dbo.TestProc @NonNullParam = 1;
GO
--Fails, as @NonNullParam not supplied
EXEC dbo.TestProc @NullParam = 1;
GO

--Fails, as @NonNullParam has NULL value
EXEC dbo.TestProc @NullParam = 1,
                  @NonNullParam = NULL;
GO

DROP PROC dbo.TestProc;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b83b772d4ce73d7762e78feb93c99a3c)

Comment: Larn**u** @Patrick ... Please at least spell my alias correctly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the other way round. Check for product name is NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Update_Lager (@productName varchar (50), @info varchar(30) , @amount int , @Preis float )
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@productName IS NULL)
    RAISERROR('You must enter the product name!', 15, 1) -- with log  
  ELSE
    BEGIN 
    ---------------------------------
    ---do everything else here------     
    Select @productName as productname, @info as info, @amount as amount, @Preis as preis
    ----------------------------------
    END
END
```

Check 1:

```
EXEC dbo.Update_Lager NULL,'xxx',10,5.0
```

Result:

```
Msg 50000, Level 15, State 1, Procedure dbo.Update_Lager, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 58]
You must enter the product name!
```

Check 2:

`EXEC dbo.Update_Lager 'abcd','xxx',10,5.0`

Result

```
productname info    amount preis
abcd        xxx     10     5
```

Took inspiration from here : [How to restrict NULL as parameter to stored procedure SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330303/how-to-restrict-null-as-parameter-to-stored-procedure-sql-server)

Comment: FYI, it is recommended that `THROW` is used over `RAISERROR` now. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): *"The **RAISERROR** statement does not honor **SET XACT_ABORT**. New applications should use **THROW** instead of **RAISERROR**.*"

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your reply. working on your answer .....